# PhoneGap/Cordova Error: Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down

Tags: cordova, photoswipe

I'm making an app for IOS, Android and WP. I'm using PhoneGap 2.7.0, testing for Android.
I get the following error in emulator Android 2.2:

`Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down`

When I swipe photos, I'm using PhotoSwipe.

No problems over there, app is working.

But in emulator Android 3.1, 4.0 or 4.0.3 I get the same error, together with:

```
Stale touch event ACTION_DOWN received from webcore; ignoring
```

The swiping doesn't work normal, and my photos sometimes disappear. When I do a few swipes the PhotoSwipe Gallery stops working at all.

I've searched this issue on Google and found a lot of people struggling with this. All solutions provided in these discussions don't do the trick for me.
I've updated all the libraries, cleaned my code, tried deleting the 'e.preventDefault()', added extra code, ... But all without effect, or with effect but worse issues like not starting the app...

I hope someone can help me, I'm trying for days to fix this!

Comment: Extra information: the first error 'miss a drag...' also appears when scrolling my pages with IScroll

Comment: Hi, Have u found the answer? Can u please help me out bcoz me too having the same problem?

Comment: I didn't find a solution, I've just used the latest version of Phonegap, and the error was gone.

Comment: Which version? I am using 2.9.0 currently.. Can you please tell??

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by listening to 'touchstart' event, and preventingDefault.

`$('.element').on('touchmove', function(ev) {`

`ev.preventDefault();`

`});`

The problem, though, it also cancel all the scroll events if there is any in the '.element' element.